# Determine center of a geometry polygon

Tags: google-earth-engine, geometry

In Google Earth Engine, I let the user define a polygon to give the geometry that the routine is applied to. As part of that, I would like to determine a "center" of the polygon. How does one extract a center of an irregular polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use to following:

```
// Compute the centroid of the polygon.
var centroid = polygon.centroid();
```